# iPhone app versions: release micro-updates often, or major updates less frequently?

Tags: iphone, release, cycle, frequency, updates

I released a new iPhone app 5 days ago. Already it has received high ratings, and many downloads, so I think it can be quite successful. (It's currently ranked in the top 10 paid music apps.)

What do you think is the best release strategy:

- Release many micro-updates, often. (Just 1 or 2 new features per update, as they are completed.)

or

- Release major updates less frequently. (Perhaps one new version every 1 or 2 months.)

The app is currently priced at $0.99 USD. Originally I planned to raise the price after the first major update. But if the app continues to sell well, I may leave the price alone.

Just curious to know how others have handled their app release cycles. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple suggests ([here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/managing.html#submit)):

> High frequency updates - crashes or data loss
>   Updates to your application
>   that address crashing and data loss
>   should be submitted as frequently as
>   necessary. Fixing as many related bugs
>   as possible in each update is highly
>   recommended.
>
> Medium frequency updates - minor
>   enhancements and usability
>   improvements Consider a release
>   schedule between two to four weeks
>   that groups together updates which do
>   not affect the core functionality of
>   your application, such as user
>   interface improvements, spelling
>   corrections, and minor functionality
>   enhancements.
>
> Low frequency updates - new features
>   Applications with new features should
>   be submitted on a periodic, monthly
>   basis. A high frequency of new feature
>   updates suggests poor development
>   planning and can be confusing to your
>   customers.customers.

They say that submitting updates really often may impact the time it takes for your updates to get approved, (because each update has to be checked manually by the app store reviewers).

Comment: In my opinion, it's not one or the other, but a combination of all 3, depending on which type of update it is. (And if my A helped, can you mark as best answer?)

Comment: So much for Apple's opinion. Does ring true for developers' interest?I'm sure Apple don't want a flood of submissions beyond what they're already getting, but consider the source of this advice.

Comment: Agree with the answer, and will also point out that each update also entitles you to get 50 additional promo codes (old ones remaining valid), which could be useful for marketing.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for not updating too frequently is that frequent updates can be annoying to users.  Each time, they have to key in their password and wait for it to download the update.

Comment: But it can also create an inconsistent user experience. They learn one UI, then a couple of weeks later that's thrown out of the window for some new locations of buttons, etc. In some cases it can be beneficial (and crucial) to the application though (Pocket God)